# How to render json without having .json at the end of the url

Tags: api, rest, cakephp, odata

I want to implement ODATA formatting to my CakePHP REST API. My problem is CakePhp expects `.json` at the end of the resource to understand the response format.

How can I render json and remove ".json" part from my request url?

I.e.

Current GET:

```
api.local/api/v2_agent_properties/83.json
```

Target GET:

```
api.local/api/v2_agent_properties(83)
```

Comment: It's not clear why current and target urls change format completely `v2_agent_properties(83)` <- why the parentheses, was that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set this in the beforeRender of the appController:

```
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. My only problem is now api.local/api/v2_agent_properties(83). How can I get "(83)" part ? I think I need some kind of routing.